# How to compare boxplots in R?

Tags: r, correlation, boxplot, anova

I have three different datasets with 3 groups. A, B and C.
each group has 3 columns:

A:
a , b and c

B:

d , e and f

C:

g, h and i

So,

Here I tried to demonstrate my data as an example:

```
A:

a <- seq(from=-1, to=4, by=0.5); b <- seq(from=-1, to=8, by=0.5); c <- seq(from=-2, to=3, by=0.5)

B:

d <- seq(from=-4, to=1, by=0.5); e <- seq(from=-3, to=2, by=0.5); f <- seq(from=-1, to=5, by=0.5)

C:

g <- seq(from=-1, to=1, by=0.5); h <- seq(from=-2, to=3.5, by=0.5); i <- seq(from=-4, to=0.5, by=0.5)
```

and I've generated boxplots for them.

```
boxplot(a,b,c, col=c(4:6))
boxplot(d,e,f, col=c(4:6))
boxplot(g,h,i, col=c(4:6))
```

**A:**

[image]

**B:**

[image]

**C:**

[image]

my question is, how can I compare group 1 ('darkblue' a,d and g) in all three boxplots to each other to see how they are correlated to each other?

and do the same for all group 2 ('lightblue' b, e and h), and group 3 ('pink' c, f and i).

I've tried to use Tukey's test with this (for first 5 cases of each group):

```
TukeyHSD(aov(lm(a[1:5] ~ b[1:5]+c[1:5])),ordered=T,conf.level=0.95)
```

but I got an error:

```
Error in TukeyHSD.aov(aov(lm(a[1:5] ~ b[1:5] + c[1:5])), ordered = T,  : 
  no factors in the fitted model
In addition: Warning message:
In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: b[1:5]
```

I know how to make factors by using cut with:

```
cut(a, seq(from=-5, to=4, by=0.2))
```

my problem is that I do not want to give a range to my data; instead, I want to compare the whole data in group 1 in the first boxplot to the other two boxplots.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: it's unclear what a,b and c are based on what's in `I have three different datasets:`

Comment: I made an example of how my datasets may look like. There are three numeric data.frames (for ex. with 3columns/3groups in each data.frame A,B,C) and I've generated 3boxplots from each dataframe.
what I want to compare is the correlation between the boxplots from each group for ex. compare only All 'A' groups from boxplots, compare all B groups to each other and C groups to each other. 

is it still unclear?

Comment: please change your code to reflect what you just described

Comment: I've done that but still nobody even read the question! :)

Comment: the boxplots cannot be generated with what you describe in `my data`, please recheck

Comment: Now it should work! I re-checked them.

Comment: 1. your vectors are of different length, 2. it is unclear what your are trying to test here and what the groups represent 3. a statistical test assumes you are trying to test for independence between groups in the same **dataset**